# .h and .m files for view controllers added within storyboard xcode 5

Tags: xcode5

i want to know how to add .h and .m files in my existing project for new view controller in xcode 5. there is no option for creating a UIViewSubClass in xcode 5.0. thanx.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select your project--->click on New File----> Select Objective-C class, then click on next button, you will see the class and subclass of....
```

You can follow the steps above to create a new class. I think this will be helpful for you.

Comment: i gt the .m and .h files but how do i link it with my view controller.??

Comment: Click on storyboard and add view controller object into story board, click on this which is added by you--> click on 'Show the identity inspector' and you can see custom class box and added the classviewcontroller what you created .h and .m file of classviewcontroller.